# F# match with for matrix

Tags: f#, matrix, pattern-matching

I would like to use a "match with" function to compare two matrix. 
I think I don't understand something about this function.
Let's take a trivial example. Consider 2 simple matrix:

```
let a  = matrix [[1.0; 1155.0; 1.0]
                 [1.0; 1156.0; 1.0]
                 [2.0; 1157.0; 1.0]
                 [3.0; 1157.0; 1.0]]
let b  = matrix [[1.; 0.; 1.0]
                 [1.0; 0.; 1.0]
                 [2.0; 0.; 1.0]
                 [3.0; 0.; 1.0]]
```

Now I would like to copy the second column of matrix "a" in matrix "b". But with the following code, I have the error which say *"error FS0010: unexpected symbole '[' in the expression. use '(', '(*)' ..."*. 
Here is the code :

```
for i = 0 to a.NumCols -1 do
    match b.[i,0] with
    | a.[i,0] -> (b.[i,1]<-a.[i,1])
    | _ -> (b.[i,1]<-a.[i,1])
```

The problem seems to come from a.[i,0] which is not recognized or unexpected. I don't understand why as I just ask to match a float (b.[i,0]) with another float (a.[i,0]).
Can you give me an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the `match` keyword is useful in this case. That is only useful if you need to do different things depending on a value of some expression. You can solve the problem easily by writing:

```
b.[0 .. b.NumCols, 1 .. 1] <- a.[0 .. b.NumCols, 1 .. 1]
```

This performs a bulk operation - it takes a *slice* that represents the entire second column of `a` and assigns it to a slice that represents the entire second column of `b`.

If you wanted to write this using `for` loop, you could use:

```
for i in 0 .. b.NumCols - 1 do 
  b.[i, 1] <- a.[i, 1]
```

For more information about using the `matrix` type, you can read [my recent blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/powerpack-matrix.aspx). It uses `matrix` to represent graphs, but it explains all the basic syntax and operations you can do with matrices.

**EDIT** To answer the additional question - if you want to check whether the matched value is the same as some other value (such as element in another matrix), then you need to use the `when` clause:

```
match a.[0,0] with
| v when v = b.[0,0] -> () // Do nothing, they are the same
| v -> a.[0,0] <- v        // Set a.[0,0] to b.[0,0] because they are different
```

Comment: Indeed my example is very trivial, but I use a pattern matching in a more complex algorithm. And I don't understand why a.[i,0] is not recognized in this "match with" code. It seems that you can only write a float such as "i" or 10 or anything but not an element of a matrix... Do you have any explanations? Btw very good blog

Comment: @fabco63 I editted my answer to add an explanation - you can only match values against patterns - if you want to test for equality with an expression, you need `when`.

Comment: Thank you again Thomas that's perfect.